# How to handle OrderedDict with one entry in Python for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, for-loop

I am using a OrderedDict like this:

```
my_data = [OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'1108'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'H\xf6rspiele f\xfcr Studenten')]), OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'989'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'Impact')]), OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'580'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'Impfgegner')]), OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'990'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'MESH')]), OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'502'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'Publikationen')])]
```

If I go through this object using a `for` loop, everything works as expected:

```
for foo in mydata:
 print(foo['@pageid'])
 print(foo['@ptitle'])
```

However, my problem is:
If the OrderedDict contains only one entry, like:

```
OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'328'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'UWE')])
```

my `for` loop will fail:

```
for foo in mydata:
print(foo['@pageid'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

...because the for loop no longer gives out `foo` with several `['ATTRIBUTE']`, instead it writes me all `attribute`-names in var `foo`.

What can I do so that the `for` loop will work on single-entry dataobjects in the same way as with multi-entry dataobjects?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are using a list of `OrderedDicts`, while in the second case you are using a single `OrderedDict` object.

So, in the first case, each of the `foo` objects from `mydata` are `OrderedDict` objects and you can access your data using `foo['key']`, but in the second example, `foo` is a key from the dictionary, which is a string.

You should check if in the second case you are really handling with a list instead of a single object.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you have a list of `OrderedDict` and in the second just an `OrderedDict`. In oder to get your for loop to work do:

```
 my_data = [OrderedDict([(u'@pageid', u'328'), (u'@ns', u'0'), (u'@title', u'UWE')])]
```

which creates a list of `OrderedDict` with 1 element.

Comment: thx Jacques, my problem is, that I cannot control wheter I get case A or case B, I have the data "as is" in my `my_data`-var.  Is there a way to transform my_data into a list with one OrderedDict entry?

Comment: You can do `if not isinstance(my_data, list): my_data = [my_data]` then.